# Is there any alternative for Zoomit on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, presentation

The drawing mode provided by zoomit is wonderful during a presentation. Is there any software on Ubuntu that provides the same functionality?

Comment: for whom may not know zoomit.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit

Features
- freeze screenshot and zoom
- live zoom in and out
- simple drawing on screenshot
- break timer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Ubuntu, you should have `compiz`, so use `compizconfig-settings-manager` to turn on some plugins. This manager is in `software-center` with plugins too.
When you will have some problems with crashing of compiz because your testing, install `fusion-icon` to quick reloading it.

`compizconfig-settings-manager` can be launched by command `ccsm`.

**Annotate** (under Extras): Drawing on the screen.

[image: screenshot]

**Enhanced Zoom Desktop** (under accessibility): Does that zoom.

[image: screenshot]

Set-up shortcut as you like and enjoy. :)

Comment: But beware: Compiz is not as stable as it was in 2010, since Unity required a lot of changes, and the Unity developers didn't care about any Compiz functionality apart from those features required by Unity itself. Expect crashes. Expect inability to log into the Unity session. Expect that you'll have to reset the Unity configuration to default values (in other words: deleting the Compiz configuration files).

Answer (score 8):

### [Gromit-MPX](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx)

You might want to give Gromit-MPX (which I authored) a try:

> Gromit-MPX is an on-screen annotation tool that works with any Unix desktop environment under X11 as well as Wayland.

It's hotkey-based so there are no widgets in your way. Also, you can configure colors, mouse button mappings and hotkeys. No zooming though, only annotations. Go [here](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx) for details.

You can install it through [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.christianbeier.Gromit-MPX).

Answer (score 0):

###### Zoomit.exe Under Wine

I got ZoomIt.exe to work with Wine (Version wine-8.21) on GNOME desktop of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

command: `wine ZoomIt.exe 2>/dev/null &`

Then ZoomIt appears as a tiny icon in the "system tray" of the entire bar at the top of the screen / the "top panel".
After  clicking on the tiny icon, Zoomit opens its configuration menu. and can be configured.
After using the mouse for picking an action from the Menu, Zooming in and Drawing with the mouse work smoothly.

However the hotkeys CTRL + 1 etc do not work. The Wine Application does not receive these hotkeys on my system.

---

###### Alternative

in `Settings`, the `Universal Access` dialog, there is a `Zoom` feature that you can toggle on and off.  I creates a big preview window, dynamically updated with the content on the current desktop.

However I cannot really recommend that `Zoom` feature. I have a dual-monitor setup with different resolutions, and there the preview window is either to big or to unrespnsive, or difficult to turn back off.

Answer (score -1):

Check out "Shutter".  It's in the repos.  It's basically a screenshot tool that lets you draw on the image with a built in tool, upload them directly to various sites, etc.

Comment: this doesn't sound like zoomit ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try flameshot, it is not what you expect, it just a screenshot utility with a nice bunch of drawing stuff.

Answer (score -2):

In Linux Mint KDE there are:

<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to magnify
<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to reduce magnification
<kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to go back to normal

They are under KWin shortcuts in settings.

I understand that is no ZoomIt, but I haven't found anything close. Most software is just a window showing a magnification which is quite useless during presentations.

I understand that it's not Ubuntu either but, it's close and maybe Ubuntu has similar settings.